# Saving Bing QuickMapServices satellite layer without losing image quality

Tags: qgis, raster, quickmapservices

I'm using QuickMapServices to add a Bing satellite layer. but when trying to save what's in the Map view to a raster layer, I notice degradation in quality as if it's doing a compression process on the image. How can you save it without losing quality?

I'm using the 'Project > Save as Image'.

As I can't use any of the Raster options like Translate or Clipper etc as they require selection of a raster first.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the resolution?

Comment: The max looks like 96dpi https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx for print high res needs to be 300-600 dpi.

Comment: when you say increase resolution - do you mean just zoom in? as I'm not sure you can access 'resolution controls' via the 'Save as image' option

Answer (score 1):

Mappuzzle is very useful to save images. It is a standalone app.

Comment: Thanks - I use a similar program Terra Incognita and then save out to OziExplorer file when I used Global Mapper.

Comment: But I'm not sure if QGIS accepts OziExplorer files?  however I was hoping to be able to extract from the Bing satellite layer.but seems this is not viable without corruption so I will explore the Mappuzzle route

Comment: Turns out using Terra Incognita was easiest option for my project. and QGIS does accept OziExplorer (.map) files.